# Why after Full GC the tenured generation occupancy size become bigger?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Below is the gc log:

```
52.425: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 102590K->0K(1265792K)] [PSOldGen: 102558K->200244K(2796224K)] 205148K->200244K(4062016K) [PSPermGen: 150880K->150880K(524288K)], 1.0870870 secs] [Times: user=1.19 sys=0.03, real=1.09 secs]
50.947: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 117493K->0K(1280576K)] [PSOldGen: 103916K->216480K(2796224K)] 221409K->216480K(4076800K) [PSPermGen: 150904K->150904K(524288K)], 1.1618650 secs] [Times: user=1.44 sys=0.04, real=1.16 secs]
```

It's strange that after Full GC the tenured generation occupancy size becomes bigger(102558K->200244K, 102558K->200244K), why?

**JVM**

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: really, how do you know that the younger gen was successfully GC'd?

Comment: @ScaryWombat what do you mean?

Comment: Think about how does stuff get into `PSOldGen`

Comment: do you mean objects in young gen is flushed into old gen? So 102590 - ( 200244 - 102558) = 205148 - 200244 = 4904k is the actual size of garbage which is collected?

Comment: could be couldn't it.

Comment: Scary Wombat answered this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858958/why-after-full-gc-the-tenured-generation-occupancy-size-become-bigger?noredirect=1#comment42279409_26858958